# Есть ли техническая возможность заблокировать телефон через ввод данных во время звонка?

Tags: телефония

Не знаю как правильно это все формулировать, но суть такова:
говорят, что появились "мошенники", которые звонят на телефон, просят ввести цифру под каким-то предлогом, вследствие чего блокируется телефон. На этом все)

В чем состоит цель мошенничества, я не в курсе), но меня заинтересовала техническая сторона вопроса.

Есть ли техническая возможность получить доступ к телефону посредством манипуляций указанных выше?

Comment: а вы уверены что задаете вопрос на подходящем по тематике ресурсе?

Comment: @xmikex -  не уверен. Но я уверен, что мне подскажут правильное направление). Да и тэг `телефония` не я придумал. Поэтому тэгу есть пару десятков вопросов не связанных с программированием

Comment: ... подумалось - что этот вопрос - потенциальный кандидат для получения знака `Некромант` )